# add request.GET variable using django.shortcuts.redirect

Tags: django, redirect, django-urls, django-views

Is possible to add GET variables in a redirect ? (Without having to modifiy my urls.py)

If I do `redirect('url-name', x)`

I get `HttpResponseRedirect('/my_long_url/%s/', x)`

I don't have complains using `HttpResponseRedirect('/my_long_url/%s/?q=something', x)` instead, but just wondering...

Comment: Small typo in the answer from Manoj Govindan: params = urllib.urlencode(**kwargs) needs to be replaced with params = urllib.urlencode(kwargs) Otherwise you get "TypeError: urlencode() got an unexpected keyword argument"

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> Is possible to add GET variables in a redirect ? (Without having to modifiy my urls.py)

I don't know of any way to do this *without* modifying the `urls.py`.

> I don't have complains using HttpResponseRedirect('/my_long_url/%s/?q=something', x) instead, but just wondering...

You might want to write a thin wrapper to make this easier. Say, `custom_redirect`

```
def custom_redirect(url_name, *args, **kwargs):
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse 
    import urllib
    url = reverse(url_name, args = args)
    params = urllib.urlencode(kwargs)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url + "?%s" % params)
```

This can then be called from your views. For e.g.

```
return custom_redirect('url-name', x, q = 'something')
# Should redirect to '/my_long_url/x/?q=something'
```

Comment: It's crazy this is not part of Django framework... Any philosophical reason behind?

Answer (score 130):

Since redirect just returns an `HttpResponseRedirect` object, you could just alter that:

```
response = redirect('url-name', x)
response['Location'] += '?your=querystring'
return response
```

Comment: Easy enough to use `urldefrag` if that's a possibility. Thanks for pointing out the potential error if you have an anchor in your url response.

Comment: Best answer ever

Comment: @Kolyunya: Are you sure? I'm using it with an anchor

Answer (score 4):

We can import urlencode from django.

```
from django.utils.http import urlencode

get_args_str = urlencode({'q': 'something'})
```

Or we can just use unparsed get parameters string  from starting request

```
get_args_str = request.META['QUERY_STRING']

HttpResponseRedirect('%s?%s' % (url, get_args_str))
```

Comment: I think the `x` should be removed to make this work.  Otherwise the contents of `x` are added as a body in the HTTP response when it should be empty.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for finding this bug. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's worth noting that Django's `RedirectView` class has a built-in class attribute `query_string` which can be overridden or passed to `as_view`. If set to `True`, `query_string` will preserve the query string in the redirect. For example, you could put the following in `urls.py`:

```py
path('example-redirect/',
     RedirectView.as_view(url='https://example.com', query_string=True),
     name='example_redirect')
```