# Redirect error with django. Nothing seems to work

Tags: python, django

I know there are many post about django redirecting. However I did not find anything like my problem. I don't know what's happening but I've read a lot and still haven't found anything about it.
So I post my code.
My project urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^backbone', include('backbone.urls', namespace='backbone')),
]
```

My app urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/shell$', views.shell, name='shell'),
    url(r'^/login$', views.login, name='login'),
]
```

My app views.py

```
def shell(request, app='cashier'):
    if 'user' not in request.session:
        response = redirect('backbone:login', app=app)
    else:
        response = render(request, 'template.html')
    return response

def login(request, app):
    context = {
        'app': app,
    }
    response = render(request, 'backbone/login.html', context)
    return response
```

The error appearing on console:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'app': 'app'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['backbone/login$']
```

The error on browser:

```
NoReverseMatch at /backbone/shell
Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'app': 'app'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['backbone/login$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.1.79/backbone/shell
Django Version: 1.10.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'app': 'app'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['backbone/login$']
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 392
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['/home/ipi/workspace/RamoSP',
 '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 24 Nov 2016 19:56:47 +0000
```

I don't understand. I am sending the args it requires, right? I've been stuck for a while now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, you are trying to access this URL:

```
url(r'^/login$', views.login, name='login')
```

with arguments that it does not expect, as it does not expect any arguments.

Have a look at [this post](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_url_mapping.htm), specifically the **Sending Parameters to Views** topic. It will help you understand why you can't send arguments to the view in this URL.

By the way, what you probably want is to send **query params** in your request to this URL. In this case, instead of:

```
redirect('backbone:login', app=app)
```

you will have to do:

```
url = '{}?app={}'.format(reverse('backbone:login'), '?item=4')
redirect(url)
```

Comment: I want to check the post you gave but it isn't a post I think.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Fixed the link.

Answer (score 3):

What do you want ?

```
/backbone/login?app=cashier
```

Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3766503/6622256

or

```
/backbone/login/cashier
```

Solution:

add argument 'app' in your route declaration:

```
url(r'^login/(?P<app>)$', views.login, name='login'),
```