# Passing parameter with reverse used with HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, django-urls

I currently have something like this

```
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("named_foo"),request)
```

How do I pass parameter to `named_foo` definition through reverse ? The parameters of named_foo definition is as follows:

```
def fooMethod(request) :
      print "inside foo method"
```

Comment: So does your `fooMethod` take any input aside from the request?

Comment: currently no I would like to pull out a parameter value using request.GET.get("key","") where key is the parameter

Comment: @Dan's answer works, or try this thin wrapper: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3766452/4044442

Comment: FYI,If fooMethod takes a parameter then you could pass an argument like this:  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("named_foo",args=(key,)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid reverse function doesn't include the GET params. But you can always do something like `'%s?key=foo' % reverse('named_foo')`